# Unable to make dynamic variables in views and url of DJANGO Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I was trying create a api like "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data/year".
but i am not able to do it, unable to dynamic the year in the endpoint.  Please check the urls.py
2nd problem - i want to make requestedYear as dynamiic in views.py.

Reference files are mentioned below. Please check.

**models.py**

```
class DataModel(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(editable=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    YearOfDate = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = DataModel
        fields = ['id', 'city', 'date', 'YearOfDate']
    def get_YearOfDate(self, obj):
        return obj.date.year
```

**views.py**

```
class DataListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    model = DataModel
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self):
        requestedYear = 2009
        return DataModel.objects.filter(date__year=requestedYear)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [ path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
path('api/data/2009', views.DataListView.as_view()),
#re_path(r'^api/match/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.DataListView.as_view()),]
```

Answer (score 2):

pass the year in your url

```
urlpatterns = [ path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
path('api/data/<int:year>', views.DataListView.as_view())]
```

kwargs will now contain the passed year in url

```
class DataListView(generics.ListAPIView):

   queryset = DataModel.objects.all()
   serializer_class = DataSerializer

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        year = self.kwargs['year']
        return DataModel.objects.filter(date_year=year)
```